# Appbar not hiding when recyclerview scrolled

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I am trying to hide appbar when user scrolled recyclerview layout code as per follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/my_appbar_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <include
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                layout="@layout/plp_header_card_view"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/item_list_recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:scrollbars="none" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to hide appbar when this screen intialize & show appbar when user scroll the recyclerview. Please help me to do this one.

Comment: app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" apply this property to immediate upper linearlayout

Comment: @ManojBhadane correct

Comment: @ManojBhadane tried the same still not working.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is proper way to make toolbar hide when the scroll down.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabanim_appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tabanim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"` on LinearLayout work hide action recycleview scroll.

But you question is **hide appbar when this screen intialize & show appbar when user scroll the recyclerview**

My suggestion as belowit will help you to achieved target
1. [Hide and show toolbar on scroll](http://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/15/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scroling%28part1%29/)
2. [you can use CollapsingToolbar](https://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/)